# iOS long lasting animations drain battery?

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, bluetooth

I'm building an app that has a gauge view with a needle that animates up and down. An Arduino sends measurements to the app at about 20 times per second over bluetooth and updates the UI every 1/8 of a second. These measurements make the needle on the gauge move with an nice animation. I wonder if this is a battery killer since it drains it at about 1% over 4 minutes (iPhone 6s). This app is meant to run over long periods of time with out being plugged in. I'd say up to two hours.

This is the animation code, nothing out out the ordinary

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.125, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
    self.needle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .toRadians(CGFloat(angle)))
})
```

Comment: what's draining your battery?  the animation, or bluetooth?  Do you lose the same 1% over 4 minutes when the animation isn't running?

Comment: It could depend on your graphics - shadows, gradients, transparent parts, etc. are expensive to draw. Did you try profiling your batter usage with Instruments - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringEnergyImpact.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH34-SW3 ?

Comment: The bluetooth does not seem to be the issue, there was practically no battery drainage before the animation. And the app is literally black and white, simple lines (UIBezierPaths) and text. I did try to profile the app using instruments, I think I need to watch a youtube tutorial or something cause I have no idea what I'm looking for.